# Printing over ssh: "cat file | lpr" or "lpr file"

Tags: command-line, ssh, printing, cat

I am looking at how to print a file over ssh. Two websites ([The Linux Documentation Project](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Printing-Usage-HOWTO-2.html) and [Computer Hope](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/ulpr.htm)) suggest the command "lpr" but both seem to suggest two different methods, with no obvious reason why they are different or which should be used in different circumstances.

Option 1:

```
lpr <filename>
```

Option 2:

```
cat <filename> | lpr
```

I understand that option 1 simply prints the file, whereas option 2 uses cat to read the file and pipes it to lpr which then prints it, but why is that useful? In what cases should I use one or the other or are they totally equivalent? (If so, surely option 1 is better as it takes less typing...)

Comment: you can use either method, maybe they did an example where it shows you can also pipe something to the printer. if i know 'cat file.txt | lpr' works other things work too. for example 'tail -n 10 /var/log/syslog | lpr'

Comment: I realise the second method could be used with other commands, but why would you ever use cat and pipe? Surely doing that is totally redundant?

Answer (score 2):

[I do realize I'm 6 years late to the party, but there is currently no answer, so I thought I'd give it a try.]

With `lpr filename`, lpr receives the filename, and has the responsibility to open that file and read its content.

With `cat filename | lpr`, lpr receives the content on the file on stdin, in a pipe (and does not even see the filename). This is often nicked as "useless use of cat" (UUOC, see e.g. https://porkmail.org/era/unix/award)

To avoid the UUOC, some people (myself included) prefer `<filename lpr` (or equivalently `lpr <filename`) which connects stdin to the file. It is similar to `lpr filename` but offers some flexibility, e.g. `<filename ssh some-machine lpr` for printing to a remote printer.

Comment: That is the idea of AU though ;-) Have an upvote. I am in the `< filename lpr` camp

Answer (score 0):

Good this question came up after this long time.

There is a serious reason for using the pipe to `lpr`. The usage with `cat` can just seen as an example.

Assume you have some images and want to put 4 images per page to printout. Without the pipe you have to create a temporary file and make sure to delete it afterwards. With the pipe, you can put several command in one line without creating a temporary file.

For an example:

```
img2pdf pic1.png pic2.png pic3.png pic4.png | pdftops - - | psnup -4 | ps2pdf  - | lpr
```